# I would like to get my json list of equipmentscontrol to transform it into a list of EquipmentControl

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization, mapping

This is my Control Model :

```
import 'package:flutter_data/flutter_data.dart';
import 'vehicle.dart';
import 'agent.dart';
import 'equipementcontrol.dart';


class Control {
  @override
  final int id;
  final String date;
  final int nbKm;
  final int fuelLevel;
  final String comments;
  final Vehicle vehicle;
  final Agent agent;
  final List<EquipementControl> equipementcontrols;


  // Constructor, with syntactic sugar for assignment to members.
  Control({
    required this.id,
    required this.date,
    required this.nbKm,
    required this.fuelLevel,
    required this.comments,
    required this.vehicle,
    required this.agent,
    required this.equipementcontrols,
  })
  {
    // Initialization code goes here.

  }
  // Construct an object from a mapped JSON array
  factory Control.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> mappedJson){
    return Control(
        id: mappedJson['id'],
        date: mappedJson['date'],
        nbKm: mappedJson['nbKm'],
        fuelLevel: mappedJson['fuelLevel'],
        comments: mappedJson['nbKm'],
        vehicle: Vehicle.fromJson(mappedJson['vehicle']),
        agent: Agent.fromJson(mappedJson['agent']),
        equipementcontrols: List<dynamic>.from(mappedJson['equipementcontrols']).map((i) => EquipementControl.fromJson(i)).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my error :

Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'map'
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49      throw*
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 768:3   defaultNoSuchMethod
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 61:17                 noSuchMethod
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 763:31  noSuchMethod
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 283:12  callNSM
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 342:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 431:10  callMethod
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 438:5   dgsend
packages/campus/model/control_rao.dart 35:38                                                                                   latestControlFromOneVehicle
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1660:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 567:5                                         [_completeWithValue]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 640:7                                         callback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                  _microtaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15

Finally this is the json (i want to get equipementcontrols list to use into the view):

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "date": "1976-11-18",
    "nbKm": 9651,
    "fuelLevel": 1,
    "comments": "Similique et velit earum praesentium culpa inventore nostrum. Distinctio quas aliquam nihil qui quis.",
    "vehicle": {
        "id": 1,
        "immatriculationPlate": "HO-152-MG",
        "status": {
            "id": 1,
            "label": "à préparer"
        },
        "model_car": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "308",
            "nbSeats": 5,
            "brand": "Peugeot",
            "logo": "LOGO_MISSING"
        },
        "bookings": []
    },
    "agent": {
        "id": 2,
        "businessName": "momo",
        "user": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "agent2",
            "email": "agent2@seven.fr",
            "active": 1,
            "lastLoginDate": "2004-05-30"
        }
    },
    "equipementcontrols": [
        {
            "id": 61,
            "RS": 0,
            "RP": 1,
            "EC": 1,
            "equipement": {
                "id": 1,
                "label": "Aile AV G"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 62,
            "RS": 0,
            "RP": 0,
            "EC": 0,
            "equipement": {
                "id": 2,
                "label": "Aile AR G"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 63,
            "RS": 1,
            "RP": 1,
            "EC": 0,
            "equipement": {
                "id": 3,
                "label": "Calandre"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 64,
            "RS": 1,
            "RP": 1,
            "EC": 0,
            "equipement": {
                "id": 4,
                "label": "Phare AV D"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 65,
            "RS": 0,
            "RP": 1,
            "EC": 1,
            "equipement": {
                "id": 5,
                "label": "Siège pass"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 66,
            "RS": 0,
            "RP": 1,
            "EC": 1,
            "equipement": {
                "id": 6,
                "label": "Porte AV G"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 67,
            "RS": 1,
            "RP": 1,
            "EC": 1,
            "equipement": {
                "id": 7,
                "label": "Aile AV D"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 68,
            "RS": 0,
            "RP": 1,
            "EC": 0,
            "equipement": {
                "id": 8,
                "label": "Aile AR D"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 69,
            "RS": 0,
            "RP": 0,
            "EC": 1,
            "equipement": {
                "id": 9,
                "label": "Phare AV G"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 70,
            "RS": 1,
            "RP": 0,
            "EC": 0,
            "equipement": {
                "id": 10,
                "label": "Siège cond"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 71,
            "RS": 0,
            "RP": 0,
            "EC": 0,
            "equipement": {
                "id": 11,
                "label": "Tableau de b"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 72,
            "RS": 0,
            "RP": 0,
            "EC": 1,
            "equipement": {
                "id": 12,
                "label": "Porte AV D"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is EquipementControl file :

```
import 'package:flutter_data/flutter_data.dart';
import 'equipement.dart';


class EquipementControl {
  @override
  final int id;
  final int RS;
  final int RP;
  final int EC;
  final Equipement equipement;


  // Constructor, with syntactic sugar for assignment to members.
  EquipementControl({
    required this.id,
    required this.RS,
    required this.RP,
    required this.EC,
    required this.equipement,
  })
  {
    // Initialization code goes here.

  }
  // Construct an object from a mapped JSON array
  factory EquipementControl.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> mappedJson){
    return EquipementControl(id: mappedJson['id'] as int,
      RS: mappedJson['RS'],
      RP: mappedJson['RP'],
      EC: mappedJson['EC'],
      equipement: Equipement.fromJson(mappedJson['equipement']),
    );
  }

}
```

And Equipement file :

```
import 'package:flutter_data/flutter_data.dart';


class Equipement {
  @override
  final int id;
  final String label;


  // Constructor, with syntactic sugar for assignment to members.
  Equipement({
    required this.id,
    required this.label,})
  {
    // Initialization code goes here.

  }
  // Construct an object from a mapped JSON array
  factory Equipement.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> mappedJson){
    return Equipement(id: mappedJson['id'] as int,
      label: mappedJson['label'],
    );
  }
}
```

I already tried removing the  on List, I also tried putting a .castFrom method instead of .from. However nothing works, if you have an idea I am a taker.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to map inside the from method, not outside.

```
List<EquipementControl>.from(mappedJson['equipementcontrols'].map<EquipementControl>((x) => EquipementControl.fromJson(x as Map<String,dynamic>),),),
```

Comment: i don't have the .fromMap() method

Comment: Ah, i changed it to fromJson. I named it fromMap

Comment: Ok i got an other error : Error: Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'int', do you have an idea why ?

Comment: Cause this is the first time i used list of object into a model by getting json

Comment: Add yoru fromJson from EquipementControl

Comment: it was already done :(

Comment: No, add it to your question so i can see it ...

Comment: This time it's done aha ;)